# expo build doesn't override the default permission strings

Tags: permissions, expo, info.plist

I have an expo app that requires location permission to list stores nearby.

In my **app.json**, I have:

```
{
  "expo": {
....
    "ios": {
     "infoPlist": {
          "NSCamera​Usage​Description": "The app would like to get an access to your camera to take 
     a profile photo"
     }
      },
}
```

And I ran **expo build:ios**

When I submit, app gets rejected because the default strings are showing instead of customized ones.

I opened **Info.plist** from *ipa* folder generated and I realized that the customized ones are there **but the default ones are also there**.

```
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow app to use your camera</string>
    <key>NSCamera​Usage​Description</key>
    <string>The app would like to get an access to your camera to take a profile photo</string>
```

and they are the ones that are showing on testflight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, when I copied the keys, they had hidden characters which I never heard off before.

[image: VScode show hidden characters like this]

I retyped the keys without copy/paste. and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Expo documentation, you need to define the permissions inside the ios.infoPlist property instead of directly providing them under 'ios' and the format is like key values. Try this :

```
{
"expo": {
....
"ios": {
     "infoPlist": {
          "NSCamera​Usage​Description": "The app would like to get an access to your camera to take 
     a profile photo"
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: sorry I just edited the question. the way you wrote it is the way I used but there was a twist. I'll answer the question. thanks